# Query only for the first n results of like

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5

What I'm trying to accomplish is a huge speedup (read: incremental results) when searching a database with a like operator which is kind of a last resort, if everything else already failed, to come up with a solution to the given search.

What I'm doing right now is that I query **mysql** with jooq like:

`dsl.select(re.ID).from(re).where(re.EXPLANATION.likeIgnoreCase("%" + contains + "%")).fetch()`

which is equivalent to

`SELECT ID from EXPLANATIONS where EXPLANATIONS.EXPLANATION like "%" + contains + "%"`

**but I really don't need the whole result** (or well, not in the first step). The reason for the slow speed is that this database-table contains some 2 million records, and the `EXPLANATION` field is `varchar(2000)` which makes it kinda slow to query (there is however an `FULLTEXT INDEX` defined for this field).

My questions would be

1. **how to, if possible, query only for the first n results of my query**
2. If there is any possible INDEX I could define to make querys like this faster for the given circumstances.

Answer (score 1):

I understand you do not want only to limit the number of returned results (which could be done with a `LIMIT` at the end of the query), but the number of records that the `LIKE` operation is applied.

One idea could be, instead of apply the `LIKE` operation on all records of EXPLANATIONS table, doing on a limited number of items of the table:

```
SELECT exp.ID FROM(select * from EXPLANATIONS limit 1000) exp WHERE 
exp.EXPLANATION LIKE "%" + contains + "%"
```

Answer (score 1):

Full text searches are often quite slow, specifically if you have a leading `%` matcher. Also, note that [jOOQ's](http://www.jooq.org), `equalsIgnoreCase()` really also adds a `LOWER()` function call to your column, which prevents index usage. You might not want to do that. To see what SQL code is rendered by jOOQ, [enable jOOQ's debug logging](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-execution/logging/). This will also help you assess whether the query is slow, or the fetching.

Given your questions:

1. Use jOOQ's [`limit(..).offset(..)`](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.2/manual/sql-building/sql-statements/select-statement/limit-clause/) clause.
2. Yes, MySQL supports a [fulltext index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html). If this query is run a lot, you'll get better results with it.